# loop in phpmyadmin

Tags: loops, phpmyadmin

I have a table of hex colors (500 rows) and a table of countries (~250rows). I would like to use a loop to go through each country, assigning a new hex color to it from the hex table in a column 'color'

Can I do this in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement with a subquery to select values from the hex table:

```sql
UPDATE `countries` SET `color` = 
    (SELECT `color` FROM `hex_colors` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

In phpmyadmin, select your database, then click on the SQL tab at the top of the admin screen. Enter the update statement, then click "Go"

**EDIT:** If you want to ensure a one to one mapping between the color values and the countries, so that no values are duplicated, I would add a temporary column to each table, i.e. `order`, run an update that would assign sequential values to that column for both tables, and then update the countries table with the color values from the hex color table, joined by `order`:

```sql
SELECT @i := 0;
SELECT @j := 0;
ALTER TABLE `countries` ADD COLUMN `order` INT;
ALTER TABLE `hex_colors` ADD COLUMN `order` INT;
UPDATE `countries` SET `order` = @i := @i + 1;
UPDATE `hex_colors` SET `order` = @j := @j + 1;
UPDATE `countries` c, `hex_colors` h SET c.`color` = h.`color` 
  WHERE c.`order` = h.`order`;
ALTER TABLE `countries` DROP COLUMN `order`;
ALTER TABLE `hex_colors` DROP COLUMN `order`;
```

Comment: Couldn't RAND() potentially put the same color in two rows? I would prefer that row 1 of hexcolors inserts into row 1 of countries and so on...

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the fact that you want a one-to-one mapping